# Split objective optimisation with function space restrictions

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am considering an optimisation problem of the following form:
$$\textrm{Minimise  } \mathcal{C}_1[y] + \mathcal{C}_2[z] \textrm{  such that  } z = y_x,$$
where $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$, and $y_x$ denotes the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C_2}$ are functionals. We can form the Lagrangian for this minimisation problem:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{C}_1[y] + \mathcal{C}_2[z] - \langle \lambda, z - y_x \rangle$$
where $\lambda(x)$ is the Lagrange multiplier corresponding to the constraint $z=y_x$. Taking functional derivatives with respect to $y$ and $z$ gives:
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta \mathcal{C}_1}{\delta y} - \lambda_x, $$
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta z} = \frac{\delta \mathcal{C}_2}{\delta z} - \lambda. $$
The optimality system (necessary condition for a minimiser) is that the above functional derivatives are zero along with the constraint $z=y_x$ being satisfied.

My question is how to place additional restrictions on the function space in which we are optimising. I know that for integral constraints, we can just add another Lagrange multiplier to account for the fact that any variations are also constrained.

Since $z = y_x$, we know that $y$ is *more* regular than $z$. Moreover, if $y$ is in a particular function space $Y$, we know that $z$ lives in the function space $Z$ of derivatives of the functions in $Y$ (e.g. if $Y$ is the space of polynomials of order $n$, then $Z$ is the space of polynomials of order $n-1$).

The sensitivity $\delta \mathcal{L}/\delta y$ is *less* regular than $\delta \mathcal{L}/\delta z$, with the former involving a $\lambda_x$ and the latter involving a $\lambda$. Moreover, if $\delta \mathcal{L}/\delta y$ is in $Y$, then it is not necessarily true that $\delta \mathcal{L}/\delta z$ is in $Z$ (e.g. if $\lambda_x$ is a polynomial of order $n$, then $\lambda$ will not necessarily live in the space of polynomials of order $n-1$).

For an easy example, let's set $\mathcal{C}_1[y] = \| y \|^2/2$ and $\mathcal{C}_2[z] = \| z \|^2/2$. We could throw away the Lagrange multiplier for $z = y_x$ and work directly with the objective $y^2/2 + y_x^2/2$, or proceed with the split form to end up with the equation to be solved by a minimizer, $y = y_{xx}$. But I want to take a step back and look at the functional derivatives:
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta y} = y - \lambda_x $$
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta z} = z - \lambda $$
If I set $\lambda_x = y$ and solve for $\lambda$, then $z - \lambda$ might not live in $Z$.

I am not really sure how to deal with this kind of problem. I guess that since I have put $z=y_x$ into the Lagrangian, I have formally unconstrained the problem from this relationship. So maybe the best I can do is to project the variables $y$ and $z$ into the correct spaces.

Comment: Can be $$
L(x,z) = C_1(y(x))+C_2(z)+\lambda(z-y'(x))\Rightarrow\cases{C_1'(y(x))y'(x)-\lambda y''(x)=0\\C_2'(z)+\lambda=0}\Rightarrow C_1'(y(x))y'(x)+C_2'(z) y''(x)=0\Rightarrow C_1(y(x))+C_2'(z)y'(x)=c_0
$$ ?

Comment: Hi @Cesareo, I saw the earlier comment which is now gone. Both $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$, and so $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ are functionals. $y_x$ denotes $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x$. I will clarify this in the question. I think your comment above mixes functional derivatives with respect to the functions $y$ or $z$ with the differential operator $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Is there a reason for not minimizing $\mathcal{L}=  C_1[y] + C_2[y']$ as a function of $y$ directly?

Comment: Hi @whpowell96. For the particular problem I am interested in, $z$ is a periodic function (not necessarily zero mean), and so $y$ is the sum of a linear and a periodic part. Without going into too much detail, minimising for $y$ directly as you suggest puts me in trouble on the numerical calculations, as it mixes up linear parts with periodic parts for which I would like to use FFTs. But I also feel I am missing some critical understanding on how I should deal with optimisation over restricted subspaces of functions of $x$.